# How to retrieve data according relation condition

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm

I have a Product and Image entity with OneToMany relation, where One Product could have many Images.

But the image could be deleted. Instead of removing data from table, what I did is disable it adding a boolean column called 'deleted'. Then if the product image is deleted, the query would return the product without image.

I made the next query that works fine when the product has an image, but I don't know how to ignore the image if it has been deleted.

** my query **

```js
const [ products, count ] = await this.productRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('product')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('product.images', 'image')
      .where([{ name: Like(`%${terms}%`) }, { description: Like(`%${terms}%`) }, { code: Like(terms) }])
      .orderBy('product.' + params.orderBy, params.orderMode)
      .offset(params.skip)
      .limit(params.take)
      .getManyAndCount()

    return { products, count }
```

** image entity **

```js
@Entity()
export class Image extends BaseEntity {
  @Column() 
  name: string
  
  @Column({ default: false })
  deleted: boolean
  
  @ManyToOne(() => Product, product => product.images) product: Product[];
}
```

** product entity **

```js
export class Product extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ length: 20 })
  code: string

  @OneToMany(() => Image, image => image.product) images: Image[]
}
```

Comment: I imagine the where bit would need a deleted column and a '0' value

Comment: I imagined the same @Strawberry and I tested it. The result was getting nothing. What I need get is the product without images but still getting the product.

Comment: Oh I see. Use a left join and move the condition to the ON clause

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reference in the where clause to your new deleted column. I would expect something like { deleted: value } to be in the query.

`` .where([{ name: Like(`%${terms}%`) }, { description: Like(`%${terms}%`) }, { code: Like(terms) }]) ``